How to find selected Option value of select tag using BeautifulSoup Python?
I am trying to get a selected value from an HTML select tag in Python.
Well, it is successful while the option attribute is set to selected="selected", but the website I am trying to scrap has a different option attribute or something like that:
html = """
        <select>
        <option value="">Please select a vlalue</option>
        <option selected value = "1">Male</option>
        <option value = "2">Female</option>
        </select>
    """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

dropdown =  soup.find('select')
for options in dropdown.find_all('option', {'selected':"selected"}):
    if options is not null:
        print(options['value'])

So my above code can not get selected value.
Can any one figure it out?

just set True for dropdown.find
dropdown = soup.find('select')

selected_option = dropdown.find('option', selected=True)
if selected_option:
print(selected_option['value'])

This code will correctly find the selected option and print its value. The key change is using selected=True in the find method, which matches any option with the selected attribute, regardless of its value.

will it work on both cases? i mean if option tag is set with (selected="selected") or (selected="").

well i figure it out my self with the following code:-
dropdown =  soup.find('select')
selected = dropdown.select_one('option[selected]')
print(selected['value'])

